# Is shadowing parent fields in PHP strictly incorrect?

Tags: php, shadowing

PHP allows shadowing parent fields, so long as their derived access level is the same or weaker than the parent's, as in FIG 1.

**FIG 1**

```
class A {
    protected $x;

    function f() {
        return $this->x;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $x = 'foo';
}

(new B)->f(); // 'foo'
```

Shadowing is used here to take advantage of PHP's field initialization. However, some linters such as [Php Inspections (EA Extended)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622) warn this is wrong and instead recommend using the constructor to initialize the field instead, as in FIG 2.

**FIG 2**

```
class A {
    protected $x;

    function f() {
        return $this->x;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->x = 'foo';
    }
}

(new B)->f(); // 'foo'
```

By rewriting the implementation of `B` to use constructor initialization we do not need to use shadowing at all.

Is shadowing strictly incorrect? If not, when should shadowing be permitted?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: online documentation for the inspection: https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#class-overrides-a-field-of-a-parent-class

Feedback is welcome.